# Flutter can't able to import library

Tags: flutter

Here is the image_picker i added in pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  url_launcher: ^4.0.3
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.0.3+3

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  image_picker:
```

I cant able to import the image picker in my class

Comment: Did you run `flutter packages get`? Did you try restarting the IDE?

Comment: Thank you.after restarting the IDE the library is working

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you run `flutter packages get`

If it still does not work restart your IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem. Things that I did and after which it worked for me were:
1. Running the command in the terminal:

```
flutter packages get
```

2. Restarting the IDE
3. Clearing up all the pending updates.

Hope it helps, make sure all the updates are completed. There's 90 percent chance it will work.